# Render an object from an array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the problem that `this.state.languages` which is an array of objects renders in react as `[{"ID":1,"NAME":"Deutsch","SHORT_NAME":"de"},{"ID":2,"NAME":"English","SHORT_NAME":"en"}]`, but when I try to access the first element with `this.state.languages[1]` it just renders as `{`. When I try to use `this.state.languages.map(...)` I get the following error: `TypeError: this.state.languages.map is not a function`. 
`this.state.languages` is an array containing objects with the properties `ID, NAME, SHORT_NAME` 
I try to render the array and the properties by using:

```
export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      languages: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/data/sprachen")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      this.setState({ languages: responseJson.data });
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <p>{this.state.languages}</p> 
        {this.state.languages.map(function(i, item){
          return <li key={i}>{item}</li>
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is my responseJson: `{"data": [{"ID":1,"NAME":"Deutsch","SHORT_NAME":"de"},{"ID":2,"NAME":"English","SHORT_NAME":"en"}]}`

Comment: What's the content of `responseJson.data`? Please share exactly the raw response body from the network dev tools.

Comment: `responseJson.data` is a string and not an array. You need to parse it as an array

Comment: It's either a typo in your own code that's not in here, or we're missing something to help. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @EmileBergeron added the responseJson to the question

Comment: Also, you could add a `console.log(responseJson)` just before the `this.setState` to make sure you're receiving the data you're expecting.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I receive the data I'm expecting, I tryed it

Comment: There's a typo in your JSX, the `.map` function is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: And `#throws the error` is invalid comment syntax in JS.

Comment: If you're receiving the data you say, `<p>{this.state.languages}</p>` should fail to render with a React error saying _"Objects are not valid as a React child"_.

Comment: You've also inverted `.map`'s callback arguments. Its callback receives `currentValue`, `index`, `array` in that order.

Comment: Other than that, changing the map to `{this.state.languages.map(({ ID, NAME }) => <li key={ID}>{NAME}</li>)}` would render something that makes sense.

Comment: I removed the # stuff (was meant to help to understand the code) and added the mssing parenthesis. I only receive "Objects are not valid as a React child" if I use `this.setState({language: responseJson})` instead of `this.setState({language: responseJson.data})`

Comment: I tryed `{this.state.languages.map(({ ID, NAME }) => <li key={ID}>{NAME}</li>)}` and still receive "this.state.languages.map is not a function"

Comment: Without a [mcve], we can't help. The code in your question works (after the changes I mentioned).

Comment: Well the misstake was done in my backend, cuz responseJson.data was {data:'[...]'} instead of {data:[...]}

Answer (score 0):

`response.json()` should give you the JSON object directly (it shouldn't be in a `data` sub-key). So the correct code should be:

```
.then(responseJson => {
    this.setState({ languages: responseJson });
})
```

Comment: No the responseJson that I fetch is: `{"data":[{"ID":1,"NAME":"Deutsch","SHORT_NAME":"de"},{"ID":2,"NAME":"English","SHORT_NAME":"en"}]}` or do you mean that my backend should provide the ressource without the sub-key?

Comment: Then what's in `data` is not encoded properly - it's a string instead of an object. I'm guessing if you do that it should work: `this.setState({ languages: Object.parse(responseJson.data) });`
})

Answer (score 0):

The map function takes current value as first argument and index as second argument

Also it is not advisable to use the index as key while rendering children as it affects performance. I did not understand your exact requirements. I have included some code for reference

```
render() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
          <ul>
            {this.state.languages.map((item, index) => <li key={item.id}>{item.NAME}</li>)}
          </ul>
      </div>
    )
}
```